# When i change my api level my http request doesn't work

Tags: android, api, httprequest

When my api level is set to 8, all is fine. But when i try to set the minSdkVersion to 11, my http request to get an xml doesn't work. I got an exception on the if.
Here is the code:

```
URL url;
    String ciao="";
    try {
      url = new URL("myurl");

      URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(); 

      HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection; 
      int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode(); 

      if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { 
        InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream(); 
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = db.parse(in);
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(dom);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        ciao=writer.toString();
      }
        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    return ciao;
```

Comment: what exceotion do you get?

Comment: Post the logcat. Try cleaning the project.

Comment: You'll never get an exception on the if.  Maybe above it.  Are you on the main thread?  In API 11+ that's no longer legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your manifest has below statement:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="number-of-version-you-want" />
```

Then

1. Clean the project
2. Re-build the project.
3. Right click project and select run so that an updated version of the APK will be generated. Use this APK.
4. Try uninstalling and re-installing the app in the mobile phone.

**Note:** 
Use [AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) in order to avoid ANR and NetworkOnMainThreadException exception on your main thread..

**EDIT:**
Please find code for your asynctask:  I have also used a progressDialog in order to display a "loading please wait" kind of message in case, the URL call takes longer time.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{   
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    .... // Some code here
    // Async task can also be called from within an onclick code.
    new AsyncTaskOperation().execute("");
}


/* Async Task called to avoid Android Network On Main Thread Exception. Web services need to be consumed only in background.     */
private class AsyncTaskOperation extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>
{

    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
     String ciao="";
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Display the loading spinner
        Dialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait.. ");
        Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        Dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar_new));

        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... paramsObj) {
         try {
              url = new URL("myurl");

              URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(); 

              HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection; 
              int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode(); 

              if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { 
            InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream(); 
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = db.parse(in);
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(dom);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            transformer.transform(domSource, result);
            ciao=writer.toString();
              }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) 
    {
        // Close progress dialog
        Dialog.dismiss();
        // Do actions with ciao string

    } // End of method onPostExecute

} // End of class AsyncTaskOperation
```

}// End of MainActivity

Comment: And can you help to do that with AsyncTask?

Comment: @user3725188: Please find updated code. You can accept as answer if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because, starting in API 11, you MUST do all network access on a background thread. If you don't, you will receieve a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. This was brought in to prevent the UI from being unresponsive while the network is accessed.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

API level 8 allows making http request from UI thread. But in higher versions making http request on UI thread will throw an exception called NetworkonMainThread exception . To confirm the issue pleasee post your error Log